# SyntaxError "Non-ASCII character '\\xca' in file..." when debugging bottle server in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, bottle

I created a simple web server using bottle to use as a mock to test an application that has to send some information to a server. However, when I tried to debug the server in PyCharm, it raised the error below:

```
SyntaxError: ("Non-ASCII character '\\xca' in file /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details", ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', 1, 0, None))
```

If I run the server in Pycharm, it runs without any problem

I'm running PyCharm CE 2020.1, on a mac with Mojave (10.14.6) and bottle.py

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60802317/289368) answer for a similar problem with django, Pycharm debugger has a problem with python code that restarts based on changes in the source code. I changed my bottle start up to:

```py
run(app, host=config['host'], port=config['server_port'], reloader=False)
```

And now it works.